# How to fix this error : simple run error with the library faster_than_requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, nim-lang, python-3.12

here is my simple code with the faster_than_requests library :

```
import faster_than_requests as requests

t = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")
print(t)
```

As you can see the code is not the problem but i am getting that as an error in my console :

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\Outlook> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Projects/Outlook/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\Outlook\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import faster_than_requests as requests
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\faster_than_requests\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . faster_than_requests import *
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1322, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1262, in _find_spec
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nimporter.py", line 1273, in find_spec
    return Nimporter.import_nim_code(fullname, path, library=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nimporter.py", line 948, in import_nim_code
    NimCompiler.compile_nim_code(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nimporter.py", line 709, in compile_nim_code
    cls.check_compile_errors(errors, library, nim_args, output, tmp_cwd, warnings)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\nimporter.py", line 496, in check_compile_errors      
    raise NimCompileException(errors[0])
nimporter.NimCompileException: faster_than_requests.nim(2, 18) Error: cannot open file: db_sqlite
```

I don't know what is wrong, i am not good with nim or whatsoever..

I tried searching online for an answer but no one was talking about that issue so i came here.

Comment: It looks like an installation/compilation error, have you looked at [these instructions](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests#windows)?

Comment: Yeah i did but still not working

Answer (score 2):

This is out of reach for you. Recent (2.0.0) [Nim update](https://nim-lang.org/blog/2023/08/01/nim-v20-released.html) removed some libraries from the `std` to their own package. In this case, `db_sqlite` has been moved to [db_connector](https://nimble.directory/pkg/dbconnector), but `faster_than_requests` package in Pypi still does the old import:

**faster_than_requests.nim**, line 2:

```
import asyncdispatch, db_sqlite...
```

When it should be

```
import db_connector/db_sqlite
```

The library has to be updated by his author to be compatible with Nim > 2.0, because if this code is failing, I'm sure there are some other incompatibilities that you cannot solve just by switching an import.

But you can still do it! As this is a *recent* thing, you can still use Nim 1.6.18, the last version before 2.0.0. With [choosenim](https://github.com/dom96/choosenim) you can have multiple Nim versions in your computer (disclaimer: I never used it on Windows, only in Linux). Once `choosenim` is installed in your machine, do this:

`choosenim 1.6.18`

And then try to run your python script.

Optionally, open an issue in the github repo for the `faster_than_requests` package.

Good luck!